# I am writing a blank database for a Discord bot, a problem with calling a function at the right time

Tags: python, sqlite

Tried everything I knew and in all places where it could work. I am writing a blank database for the Discord bot, I stalled at the moment how exactly to call functions when needed, please tell me how to do it correctly x((((

````
from sqlite3 import Error

def sql_connection():
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(r'E:/Python/discord_bot/DATA_BAZES/test.db')
        return conn

    except Error:
        print(Error)    

conn = sql_connection()

h = input('Enter operation code')

cur = conn.cursor()         #позволяет делать SQL-запросы к БД  


#conn = sqlite3.connect(r'E:/Python/discord_bot/DATA_BAZES/test.db') #создание/подключение к базе данных
def create_table():
    cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS depositors(
        operationID INT,
        staticID INT PRIMARY KEY,   
        fname TEXT,             
        lname TEXT,
        deposit INT); 
    """)          #создание таблицы #основной ключ переменная INT #столбцы с данными
    conn.commit() #сохранение данных

if h == 0:  
    create_table()  
    


def plus_member():
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO depositors(operationID, staticID, fname, lname, deposit) 
        VALUES('00001','75173', 'Artem', 'Nejdanov', '100000');""")             #добавление значений в таблицу
    conn.commit()   #сохранение данных

if h == 1:      
    plus_member()```
````

Comment: Please tell us exactly what your error is and what triggers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you made two mistakes:

First:
Your import gets you into some trouble.
When doing `from sqlite3 import Error` you are only importing the object `Error` while other elements of `sqlite3` will not be imported.
This results into `sqlite3.connect(<loaction>)` being not correct.
Fix by changing:

```
from sqlite3 import Error
...
except Error:
    print(e)
...
```

to:

```
import sqlite3
...
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print(e)
...
```

-> this will import all of sqlite3-module
-> additionally it will store your error to the variable `e` which you can print to see your error correctly

Second:
When testing `if h == 0:` or `if h == 1:` the result will be `False` as `h` will be a string (which you are always receiving by pythons `input()`.
Therefor you could just change:

```
if h == 0:
...
if h == 1:
...
```

to:

```
if h == '0':
...
if h == '1':
...
```

-> a string gets checked against a string so your if-condition will be `True`